# How to use the same base url prefix for category and product pages in Woocommerce?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting, permalinks, woocommerce

I checked out this article https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/ which explains that it is not good to remove the product and category bases from the url because it will impact performance.

Instead of this, I did the following:

1. In woocommerce I did not set any page for the shop url so my shop page is considered the homepage
2. I have a custom made `example.com/shop/` as a page , which exports my design and products
3. In the permalink settings i have set the following:

   - Product category base: shop
   - product permalink: `/shop/%product_cat%/`

So in this way my links became the following:
categories: `example.com/shop/category-name`
products: `example.com/shop/category-name/product name`

I am satisfied with the "look" of this url structured because it makes sens to me and to a customer. the `/shop/` page is crawlable too (as opposed to a normal prefix that does not exist ) because I created it and displays the products too.

However the category pages now give a 404 error message, but the product pages work. 
If anyone has a good recommendation on how to fix this issue that will not affect performance.
I am not entirely sure what kind of performance impact will it have if I remove the prefixes as explained in the woocommerce article I linked. Is there a good fix to this?